# Autocompletion and function definition in Python Interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, autocomplete, python-interactive, ptpython

See the below GIF 
[image: Link]

> How does the documentation for all the functions appear as you type in
>   the terminal?

I am already familiar with autocompletion and there are bunch to tutorials to do this but what about function definition? Currently I am using `pip install ptpython` module to get autocompletion feature but I want to know the function definition as well. Could anyone help me?

Comment: OMG I want that! After pip install, when I try `ptpython` in the cygwin shell, it throws an error, but cmd works fine... :( HATE U WindDohs! xD

Comment: That is a bpython shell, just look at the source

Comment: https://github.com/bpython/bpython/blob/master/bpython/autocomplete.py

Comment: thank you @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 2):

Got my answer from @Padraic Cunningham. See the comment section.

This is a bpython shell. You can download using `pip` or `apt-get install bpython`

```
pip install bpython
sudo apt-get install bpython
```

To start go to your terminal and type `bpython`

[image]